# OpenLayers read.JSON with Angular

Tags: json, angular, openlayers

I want to read and display a json file from the url: 'geodat.geojson'.
The problem is that i can display the normal map with OSM but the geoJSON file will not be readed and displayed. 
Anyone can help me?

```
initMap() {
this.map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM({
        attributions: []
      })
    }), new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        url: 'geodat.geojson',
        format: new GeoJSON()
      }),
      style: new Style({
        fill: new Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255,255,5,0.8)'
        }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)'
        })
      })
    })
  ], view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
```

Comment: can you share where is 'geodat.geojson' located ? is it in same directory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the relative path of the geojson, set the projection and style the features according to feature type.

```
var styles = {
  'Point': new Style({
    image: new Icon({
      src: './marker.png'// should be in same directory
    })
  }),
  'LineString': new Style({
    fill: new Fill({
      color: '#3985da'
    }),
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: '#3985da',
      width: 2
    }),
    image: new Circle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new Fill({
        color: '#ffcc33'
      })
    })
  }),
  'Polygon': new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: '#3985da',
      width: 2
    }),
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(57, 133, 218, 0.4)'
    }),
  })
};
var styleFunction = function (feature) {
  return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
};
initMap() {
this.map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM({
        attributions: []
      })
    }), new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        url: './geodat.geojson',//if geojson is in same directory
        format: new GeoJSON()
      }),
      style: styleFunction
    })
  ], view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
```

Able to get the desired results from above code in **Openlayers 6.1.1**

Comment: when i add the projection this failure will be displayed: Argument of type '{ url: string; format: GeoJSON; projection: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'projection' does not exist in type 'Options'.

Comment: ok got it. Did it work without projection? which version of openlayers you are using?

Comment: no it didnt work . im using the last version v6.1.1

Comment: when i open the console in my navigator , this failure will be displayed :
GET http://localhost:9000/geodat.geojson 404 (Not Found)

Comment: where is your geojson located?

Comment: in the same directory of my component

Comment: can you place geojson in assets folder and try the relative path in source of vector layer like  url: 'path to assests/geodat.geojson'. and let me know about the results.

Comment: also you can verify your geojson from these sources [geojson.io](https://geojson.io/) and [geojsonLint](http://geojsonlint.com/).

Comment: you mean like this?  url: 'src/main/webapp/app/main-page/background-map/geodat.geojson'

Comment: url: 'assets/geodat.geojson'